# Getting only top values within each group that have the same column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
   1           a         100
   1           r         100
   1           h         200
   1           j         200
   2           a         50
   2           q         50
   2           k         40
   3           a         10
   3           q         150
   3           k         150
```

Imagine I am trying to get the top values of each groupby('Column 1')

Normally I would just .head(n) but in this case I am also trying to get only top rows with the same Column 3 value like:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
   1           a         100
   1           r         100
   2           a         50
   2           q         50
   3           a         10
```

Assuming the table is already in the order I want it

Any advice would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print df.groupby('Column 1')['Column 3'].first().reset_index()
   Column 1  Column 3
0         1       100
1         2        50
2         3        10

print pd.merge(df, 
               df.groupby('Column 1')['Column 3'].first().reset_index(), 
               on=['Column 1','Column 3'])

   Column 1 Column 2  Column 3
0         1        a       100
1         1        r       100
2         2        a        50
3         2        q        50
4         3        a        10
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit pd.merge(df, df.groupby('Column 1')['Column 3'].first().reset_index(), on=['Column 1','Column 3'])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.58 ms per loop

%timeit df[(df.assign(diff=df.groupby('Column 1')['Column 3'].diff().fillna(0)).groupby('Column 1')['diff'].cumsum() == 0)]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.06 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hi, this gives me the duplicated values of subset column 3, however I need the top rows for each column 1 group that correspond to the first value in column 3. So in your example it would be: Column 3: group 1  bb group 2 dd dd

Answer (score 0):

My solution (without merging):

```
In [83]: idx = (df.assign(diff=df.groupby('Column1')['Column3'].diff().fillna(0))
   ....:          .groupby('Column1')['diff'].cumsum() == 0
   ....:       )

In [84]: df[idx]
Out[84]:
   Column1 Column2  Column3
0        1       a      100
1        1       r      100
4        2       a       50
5        2       q       50
7        3       a       10
```

Explanation:

```
In [85]: df.assign(diff=df.groupby('Column1')['Column3'].diff().fillna(0))
Out[85]:
   Column1 Column2  Column3   diff
0        1       a      100    0.0
1        1       r      100    0.0
2        1       h      200  100.0
3        1       j      200    0.0
4        2       a       50    0.0
5        2       q       50    0.0
6        2       k       40  -10.0
7        3       a       10    0.0
8        3       q      150  140.0
9        3       k      150    0.0

In [86]: df.assign(diff=df.groupby('Column1')['Column3'].diff().fillna(0)).groupby('Column1')['diff'].cumsum()
Out[86]:
0      0.0
1      0.0
2    100.0
3    100.0
4      0.0
5      0.0
6    -10.0
7      0.0
8    140.0
9    140.0
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That's assuming I always need only the top two of each group but I am looking at getting ALL rows that correspond to the top value of Column 3 for each group

Comment: @EduardKim, could you post another sample data sets, because it's not quite clear?